# TFS: Auto check out files modified in Beyond Compare

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I modified some files outside TFS using beyond compare on file system, how do I have them auto checked out for check-in later?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to a local workspace. They don't have the same model and you can edit the files in any tool you like and TFS will automatically know that the files have been edited.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/05/set-local-workspaces-as-default-when-upgrading-to-tfs-2012.aspx

You will need to use Visual Studio 2012 against TFS 2012 as a minimum. It's an easy upgrade process on both ends and there really is no reason to stay on 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can autocheckout if you don't use TFS to do it.

if you hook in [Beyond Compare as the comparison tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) it may well do the checkout, but I'm not sure.

You can check out the files at any time with out changing their state in your local workspace by just right clicking on the file in source control and selecting check out, or if you have power tools installed you can do it from the File system with the built in TFS context menu option.